# Securing Solr/Tomcat on Windows

Tags: windows, tomcat, windows-server-2008, solr, security

I need to secure a Solr/Tomcat instance running on Windows 2008. All read/write clients are within the LAN, so I have followed the Tomcat instructions [here](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Securing_tomcat) and the Solr instructions [here](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrSecurity). I am unsure that is enough,

1. could you offer me any additional suggestions? or share how you go about securing Solr/Tomcat+Windows.
2. I also would appreciate suggestions on how you go about "white-hat" testing for vulnerabilities.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea what you did specifically, so it's hard to answer the question. But if you configured Tomcat to require authentication, and set up your firewall so Tomcat is not reachable from the outside, then it should be good enough for most purposes.